# error: cannot access zzaclass file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: android

I'm trying to run but always appear this error!!

Here is my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'

implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'

//customDep
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
implementation 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

//facebook share
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
```

And here is where the error is:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivityServer.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            ;

        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

The message says it's exactly at, right after "remoteMessage":

```
RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
```

I searched another similar questions, they answered to update gradle version of google services, etc, but it didn't worked in this case.

Comment: It is definitely because of version upgrade of your relative GMS version. downgrade it again to access old features.

Comment: What is the best version?

Comment: Not the best version,  but you have to look for the version you used before,  which was having that methods...  Because they update almost every new version and change methods.